# Sequence of actions not as expected in an epic in case of an inner epic is dispatching actions too

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, rxjs6

I'm using React, Redux, Redux-Observable and rxjs. In a (main) epic are some actions and another epic listed. The actions of the 'inner' epic are called at the end of main epic and not as expected between action1 and action3. The sequence change hapened after updating all node modules (RXJS from V5 to V6)...

I have created a sandbox where you can see the current behavior: https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-wozniak-bbvd0y?file=/src/epics/mainEpic.js

My main epic looks like:

```
import { Observable, from, concat, of, merge, forkJoin } from 'rxjs';
import { ofType } from 'redux-observable';
import { mergeMap, concatMap, switchMap, map, delay, debounceTime, takeUntil, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import * as actions from '../actions';
import * as types from '../actions/types';

const mainEpic = (action$, store, deps) => {
  return action$.pipe(
    ofType(types.MAIN_EPIC),
    mergeMap( action => of(
      actions.action1(action.payload.oldValue),
      actions.innerEpic(action.payload.newValue),
      actions.action3(action.payload.newValue)
    ))
  )
}
export default mainEpic;
```

I expect that action1 will be executed, then action2 (which is defined in the inner epic), and at the end action3.

The inner epic:

```
import { Observable, from, concat, of, merge, forkJoin } from 'rxjs';
import { ofType } from 'redux-observable';
import { mergeMap, concatMap, switchMap, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import * as actions from '../actions';
import * as types from '../actions/types';

const innerEpic = (action$, store, deps) => {
  return action$.pipe(
    ofType(types.INNER_EPIC),
    switchMap( action =>
      of(
        actions.epicAction2(action.payload)
      )
    )
  )
}

export default innerEpic;
```

Action1, action2 and action3 will be handled in my reducer:

```
import * as types from "../actions/types";

const defaultState = { data: [] };

export default function(state = defaultState, action) {
  console.log(`    *** reducer controllersTaken called with action type '${action.type}'`)
  try{
    switch (action.type) {
      case types.ACTION_1:
        return state;

      case types.ACTION_2:
        return state;

      case types.ACTION_3:
        return state;

      default: 
        return state;
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('ERROR', err);
    return state;
  }
}
```

Here how the action/index.js looks like:

```
import * as types from '../actions/types';

export const mainEpicCall = payload => {
  console.log(' --- dispatch main-epic');
  return (
    function(dispatch, getState) {
      dispatch({
        type: types.MAIN_EPIC,
        payload
      });
    }
  );
}

export const action1 = payload => {
  console.log(' --- dispatch action1');
  return (
    function(dispatch, getState) {
      dispatch({
        type: types.ACTION_1
      });
    }
  );
}

export const innerEpic = payload => {
  console.log(' --- dispatch inner-epic');
  return (
    function(dispatch, getState) {
      dispatch({
        type: types.INNER_EPIC,
        payload
      });
    }
  );
}

export const action3 = payload => {
  console.log(' --- dispatch action3');
  return (
    function(dispatch, getState) {
      dispatch({
        type: types.ACTION_3,
        payload
      });
    }
  );
}

export const epicAction2 = payload => {
  console.log(' --- dispatch action2');
  return (
    function(dispatch, getState) {
      dispatch({
        type: types.ACTION_2,
        payload
      });
    }
  );
}
```

To complete the code, here the action types definitions:

```
export const MAIN_EPIC = 'main_epic';
export const INNER_EPIC = 'inner_epic';

export const ACTION_1 = 'action_1';
export const ACTION_2 = 'action_2';
export const ACTION_3 = 'action_3';
```

I was expecting in the console something like

```
--- dispatch main-epic
   *** reducer controllersTaken called with action type 'main_epic'
--- dispatch action1
--- dispatch inner-epic
   *** reducer controllersTaken called with action type 'action_1'
   *** reducer controllersTaken called with action type 'inner_epic'
--- dispatch action2
   *** reducer controllersTaken called with action type 'action_2'
--- dispatch action3
   *** reducer controllersTaken called with action type 'action_3'
```

but I got

```
--- dispatch main-epic
   *** reducer controllersTaken called with action type 'main_epic'
--- dispatch action1
--- dispatch inner-epic
--- dispatch action3
   *** reducer controllersTaken called with action type 'action_1'
   *** reducer controllersTaken called with action type 'inner_epic'
   *** reducer controllersTaken called with action type 'action_3'
--- dispatch action2
   *** reducer controllersTaken called with action type 'action_2'
```

How can I manage it that the action2 of inner epic is dispatched in the correct sequence, between action1 and action3?

I'm using following node modules:

```
"dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "normalizr": "^3.6.2",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.0",
    "redux": "^4.1.2",
    "redux-observable": "^2.0.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.7"
  },
```

Comment: When I add parameter `delay(0),` in the pipe() function of the mainEpic, the sequence of dispatched actions is correct... But when I add a delay parameter to the innerEpic, it is broken again... Looks strange for me...

Comment: A possible solution is, that I move the action(s) of the inner epic to a function foo(), and call this function from the parent epic and the inner epic. The inner epic is used in other cases, so that's the reason why I would like to keep the inner epic...